# Getting Error "Either BOF or EOF is true ..." when trying to assing recordset to array

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

When trying to run this script I'm getting the error "Run-time error '3021' Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record."

```
Function ExecuteSelect(sSelect As String) As Variant

    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim a As Variant

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    OpenConnection

    rs.Open sSelect, DBCon, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

    a = rs.GetRows

    CloseConnection

    ExecuteSelect = a
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug was caused by my watches.

In my watch list trying to debug another problem I had set up the following watch

```
rs.GetRows
```

Removing this watch solved my issue.